# Parsing the response from Facebook FQL and displaying it in proper format

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

How to get list of friends using my app in an activity using Facebook API?Currently developing an app with the use of Facebook API to **show list of friends to the user whom have installed my app**.I have tried using Graph API explorer like "**me/friends?fields=name,likes,installed**" but i want to know how get the desired result in my Android App Activity.
Now i am able to get this using FQL query:

```
{Response:responseCode:200, graphObject:GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GrahObject,state=
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": xxxx98471, 
      "name": "ABC"
    }, 
    {
      "uid": xxx425672424, 
      "name": "XYZ"
    }
  ]
},error:null, isFromCache:false}
```

So how to format this output and display it in proper manner as:
Name: ABC
Name: XYZ 
in listview or so...
**I have tried using:**

```
public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                String s = textViewResults.getText().toString();
                if (graphObject != null) {
                    if (graphObject.getProperty("id") != null) {
                        s = s + String.format("%s: %s\n", 
                                graphObject.getProperty("id"), 
                                graphObject.getProperty("name"));
                    }
                }
                textViewResults.setText(s);
            }
        }));
    }
    request.executeAsync();
```

I am getting "null" in the result. So now can anybody tell me how to parse this type of response.**Any help would be highly appreciated.**

Comment: have u integrate the facebook sdk in your code?

Comment: Yes,i have already integrated Facebook SDK and able to Log In to my app...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                String s = textViewResults.getText().toString();
                if (graphObject != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                    try {
                     JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                     for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                         JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                         Log.d(TAG, "id = "+object.get("id"));
                      }
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }
                textViewResults.setText(s);
            }
        }));
}
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: @Vivek - thanks, this is perfect! Is there a way to save the graphObject into a member variable inside my class to increase its scope? Right now, the scope of graphObject is restricted to the onCompleted() method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me/friends"));
            final JSONArray friends = json.getJSONArray("data");
            if (friends != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < friends.length(); i++) {
                    String id =
              friends.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");                     
                    String name = friends.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                        Log.i(id,name);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I am able to get the result but in raw form like we used to get while running GRAPH API EXPLORER in Facebook as: {
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": xxx398471, 
      "name": "ABC"
    }, 
    {
      "uid": xxxx25672424, 
      "name": "XYZ"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: So now how to convert this and show it to the user in proper manner like: Name : ABC and Name:XYZ